# I need to cancel play for Jan. 30

Tags: scheduling

I need to cancel for tomorrow, Jan. 30. I am registered at tee 1B, along with Gary Alphin, Rick Maier, & Austin Troy.  I am unable to play.

Comment: Hi, you need to contact the organization holding the event directly. This is a software Q&A site. That organization probably uses the CiviCRM software, but they are the only ones who know about or manage the event.